# Perform calculation and display the result in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am new in Flutter
i need your help please,

I want to take an amount from the user and multiply it by 20 and want to show it how to do?
Can someone tell me the code how it happens? if possible

This is the interface

Comment: add some code of UI or somethings so we can add from our side for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry i forgot but next time i will take care @MohammedAli

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  int? result;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: controller,
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text('Calculate'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    result = int.parse(controller.text) * 20;
                  });
                },
              ),
              result != null ? Text(result.toString()) : Container(),
            ] 
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @BrijeshNavadiya No problem! Remember to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I want to show $ sign with result value please tell me how can do that

Comment: Could you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

try below code for your desire output

**Output :-**

[image]

**Code :-**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CalculationExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalculationExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CalculationExample> createState() => _CalculationExampleState();
}

class _CalculationExampleState extends State<CalculationExample> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  int? result;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
          InkWell(
            child: const Text('Calculate'),
            onTap: () => setState(() {
              result = int.parse(controller.text) * 20;
            }),
          ),
          result != null ? Text("\$$result") : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```